# Save Backbone.js Model and update entire Collection

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to be able to call save() on a backbone model and have the backend return the entire collection of this model instead of only the changed attributes of the model. I would then like backbone to update the entire returned collection. The use case for this is the following:

A user has multiple addresses and can choose a shipping address from this collection. If she chooses a different shipping address from the collection the previous shipping address should be updated to the state of 'just another plain address'. For this the entire collection has to be updated instead of only the changed model.

Is this somehow possible in backbone.js?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

models that are bound to collections, contain their collection parent as a property.  Also, since your returning a list of models, we can assume that it is always in a list.

```
mymodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   parse: function (data) {
     if(this.collection && typeof(data) === 'array') {
        this.collection.reset(data);
     }
     return data;
   }
});
```

Comment: "typeof(data) === 'array'" should be "_.isArray(data)" instead, btw.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that overriding sync or breaking the expectations of what save returns is necessary here.

It would be simpler I guess to override `save` on the model, something on the lines of:

```
save: function (key, value, options) {
    var p = Model.prototype.save.call(this, key, value, options),
        self=this;
    if (this.collection) {
        p.done(function () { self.collection.fetch(); });
    }
    return p;
}
```

which will save using the normal `save` obtaining its promise, and then if saving was successful and the model is part of a collection, it will fetch the collection from the server.

Another way would be to bind to the model's `change` event, check if it belongs to a collection and fetch, but that would also happen on `set`.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I guess this would actually work with the little inconvenience of an extra request cycle.

Comment: @Hendrik Where do you see the extra cycle?

Comment: Well if I don't miss anything here the model gets saved first and if that was successful then the client fetches the collection. If instead the server just returns the collection directly once the model was successfully stored, the whole operation needs one less request. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you are not! I had missed what you were actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's possible. You'll need to override the `sync` function on the model

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  sync: function(method, model) {
    if (method === 'create') {
      //perform save logic and update the model's collection
    } else if (method === 'update') {
      //perform save logic and update the model's collection
    } else if (method === 'read') {
      ...
    } else if (method === 'destroy') {
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

Take a look at the Backbone.sync function for more information.

Comment: I guess overriding sync doesn't help too much for this use case since it isn't concerned with the response coming back from the server (that being the task of the success callback method)

Answer (score 0):

What your use case actually calls for is the updating of two models, not the updating of an entire collection. (Other than fetching, collections don't interact with the server in Backbone.) Assuming you have addresses A, B, and C, with A as the current shipping address and C as the new shipping address, your code can simply:

1. Update C to be the new shipping address.
2. Update A to be 'just another address.'

If your problem is that you don't *know* which address is the current address (i.e., address A), then you can just search inside your collection for it (i.e., "give me the current shipping address"), update C, and then update the returned address (address A).

If you *absolutely* need to update an entire collection (you don't), cycle through `collection.models` and update each one individually. There simply is no concept in Backbone of a collection being acted upon RESTfully.

**Edit:** I may have misread your question. If you meant update the collection on the client (i.e., you didn't intend to update the collection on the server), then the code is still similar, you just update both the old model and the new one.

Comment: yes I actually meant to update the collection on the client and this is also the problem with the approach above because if I would simply update C and A to their new state on the client their state would be out of sync with the server if it couldn't be saved on the server successfully.